# Landing files in different directories in hdfs kafka, flume

Tags: key, hdfs, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, flume

I want to send csv files from one server (Unix Server A) to hdfs directories. Based which csv files I want to land them in different directories in hdfs.

I have a 11 csv files that are going to be sent by kafka producer on unix server A to kafka. The first element of the csv file will contain a key. I want to take the first element and make it the key of kafka message. Also, I want to send the value of the data as the message in kafka.

When it hits the kafka cluster, there will be a flume agent that ingests the data and and interceptor that sorts the data by key to direct it to 11 kafka-topic channels (as the channel in flume). The channels will then redirect the data to the appropriate hdfs directory.

Does this design make sense? Or is there a better way to do it? Maybe spark-streaming?

Comment: You might also consider using Kafka Connect and the Confluent Open Source HDFS Sink Connector ( see https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs)

Comment: unfortunately, not available on our cluster (CDH) yet.

Answer (score 0):

The setup you have mentioned seems all good on a first sight.

The interceptors are a good way to put event details to headers. However, you have mentioned that it would be the channels sorting / directing the messages. Instead of that, you might want to specify the **header** you add in the **interceptor** as a part of the **path** in the hdfs sink.